# Why does VBA come out of debug mode when ".paste" method is used to paste data from cell in MS Excel to a cell in a MS Word table?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste, onerror

The code below is intended to be used to copy a string from cells in an excel column sequentially **(i=3 to 61)**, find a directory folder containing many copies of the same .doc file , and paste each string into  the **second** row, **first** column of the first table in each .doc file.

Problem:  The program un intentionally continues through loop and finishes running the rest of the code after executing the following line for the first time:

```
wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Paste
```

This happens even though I am stepping into each line of code using F8 to reach this line of code. The code finishes running without having pasted anything into the remaining files in the directory. (The string in row 3 of the excel document was successfully pasted into ***plan template - Copy (10).docx***  but the remaining strings were not pasted into the remaining files)

**The code:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyExcelToWord(path As String)

'variables----------------------------------------------------------------

'Decare Object variables for the Word application and file or documentl
Dim wdapp As Object, wddoc As Object, i As Integer

'Declare a String variable for the directory root and current file in that directory
Dim currentPath As String


'main process----------------------------------------------------------

'error handling is extremely important in making Excel work with Word
On Error Resume Next
'GetObject needs two parameters. The first is optional
Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
Err.Clear
'we create a new instance of MS Word
Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

'Our application is made visible

wdapp.Visible = True

currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)

For i = 3 To 61
Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
Debug.Print currentPath



        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And Left(currentPath, 1) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print path & currentPath
           
            Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
            'we activate our MS Word instance
            wdapp.Activate
            Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents(path & currentPath)
            If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(path & currentPath)
            wddoc.Activate
            wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Paste
            'Free alocated memory and close
            wdapp.Quit
            Set wddoc = Nothing
            Set wdapp = Nothing
        'The following line of code removes the cell selection in Excel
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        currentPath = Dir()
        Else
        
        currentPath = Dir()
        
        End If


           
Loop


Next
End Sub
```

**The print ( I have placed a '**...**' where I have omitted a section of the path ):**

> .
> .
> ..
> .
> plan template - Copy (10).docx
> L
> C:**...**\ plan template - Copy (10).docx

The program runs through the rest of code unintentionally. The string in row 3 of the excel document was successfully pasted into ***plan template - Copy (10).docx*** and but the remaining strings were not pasted into the remaining files )

> plan template Copy (11).docx
> L
> C:**...**\plan template - Copy (11).docx
> Lesson plan template - Copy (12).docx
> L
> C:**...**\plan template -Copy (12).docx
> plan template - Copy (13).docx
> L
> C:**...**\ plan template -
> L
> **...**
> C:**...**\plan template - Copy (9).docx
> Lesson plan template.docx
> L
> C:**...**\plan template.docx

Comment: As per comment below and also after first End If put the line _On Error GoTo 0_ and then replace _Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy_ with _ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 2), ws.Cells(i, 2)).Copy_ and make sure you put the sheet to copy from into a variable called ws at start of code i.e. _Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")_ (or appropriate sheet name)

Comment: I have come across a few instances where a call will cause the code to continue instead of stepping. I would call that a bug in the VBA debugger. Oh the irony.

Comment: @QHarr - Thanks for your suggestion. I followed your instruction but get a run-tim error 9  " subscript out of range error". The code above comes from a module named 'Module1'. I call the module from sheet1 in the workbook. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @HackSlash. Hah, Yes it's quiet possible that this debugger is rusty...On this instance.. I sincerely hope not.

Comment: @QHarr. I solves run-time error name by changing 'sheet1' to the custom sheet name. However the program now only reaches the line :  Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents(path & currentPath) before i get the run time error 4160 - "application defined or object defined error"

Comment: I have now commented out: Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents(path & currentPath)' and i am back the the original problem. The first  paste executes and the remaining pastes dont. The Debugger continues through code instead of stepping in as intended.

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard when you are only transferring the value of a single cell? Why not use `wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value` instead?

Comment: I don't know what's causing it but have to tried placing a break point in the code after where it jumps ahead to make it stop again?

Comment: 4160 should be a bad file name. Have you checked that path & currentPath returns an actual valid filepath at point error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'issue' is nothing to do with the paste command.

Your code sets all errors to be ignored, creates a Word application object, then enters a loop where:

1. a cell value is copied
2. a Word document is opened
3. the contents of the clipboard are pasted into a table cell in the Word document
4. Word is shut down and the application object destroyed

The first iteration of the loop will run successfully but subsequent iterations will error at each line that involves Word as the object no longer exists. Those errors are ignored because of `On Error Resume Next`.

What you need to do:

1. Reset error handling after the Word object has been obtained
2. Add a flag if Word wasn't open so that it can be shut down when operations are complete
3. Close the document and save the changes once it is finished with inside the loop
4. Move `wdapp.quit` outside the loop

As Word retains clipboard history and you are only copying the value of a single cell I would avoid using copy paste for this. Instead write the value directly to the table cell.

This is how I would write your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyExcelToWord(path As String)

   'variables----------------------------------------------------------------

   'Decare Object variables for the Word application and file or document
   Dim wdapp As Object, wddoc As Object, i As Integer

   'Declare a String variable for the directory root and current file in that directory
   Dim currentPath As String

   'declare flag to show if Word needs to be quit
   Dim quitWord As Boolean
   
   'main process----------------------------------------------------------

   'error handling is extremely important in making Excel work with Word
   On Error Resume Next
   'GetObject needs two parameters. The first is optional
   Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   If Err.Number = 429 Then
      Err.Clear
      'we create a new instance of MS Word
      Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      'as Word wasn't already open make application visible
      wdapp.Visible = True
      'set flag to show Word needs to be shut down
      quitWord = True
   End If

   'reset error handling so that any subsequent errors aren't ignored
   On Error GoTo 0
   
   currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)

   For i = 3 To 61
      Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
         Debug.Print currentPath

         If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And Left(currentPath, 1) <> "" Then
            Debug.Print path & currentPath
           
            Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(path & currentPath)
            wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value
            'document no longer required so close and save changes
            wddoc.Close -1 ' SaveChanges:=Word.wdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges
            Set wddoc = Nothing
            
            currentPath = Dir()
         Else
        
            currentPath = Dir()
        
         End If
      Loop
   Next
   
   'Now that operations involving Word are complete quit Word if necessary and destroy objects
   If quitWord Then wdapp.Quit
   Set wdapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done as you and slightly snarky have advised. The code line : wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = Sheet1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value and addition of quitWord flag seems to has stopped the unwanted code continuation on debug mode. However I now get a runtime error 5 ( invalid procedure call or argument) on the line: 'currentPath = Dir()' (above the 'else' statement).

Comment: @EmptyStack - are you sure that you have 59 files in that folder?

Comment: Short answer No. question: is this required for the code to work? I have 59 cells in which there are 59 unique strings. It is intended that each document will have one of the 59 unique strings. If currentPath= Null string is satisfied before I have copied the last string then the loop will break which just means i need to add more templates documents to the directory file. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @EmptyStack - if it is your intention that each of the strings is added to a document, then yes you need 59 documents. This is the weak point of your solution. If you remove the outer loop and have more than 59 documents your code will break. If you leave the outer loop in but have fewer than 59 documents, your code will break. There is a solution to that, but you need to ask a separate question.

Comment: I removed a line of code which to change the name of the document after i had pasted the string into it: If Dir(currentPath) <> "" Then Name currentPath As newFileName because his was causing the  currentPath = Dir() line to give a runtime error.  The code runs as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain that fixing this will solve your problem, but you have

```
        wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Paste
        'Free alocated memory and close
        wdapp.Quit
        Set wddoc = Nothing
        Set wdapp = Nothing
```

Once you have done wdapp.Quit, you no longer have a wdapp, so in the next iteration of your "For i" loop, nothing will work.

But if you want to save your wddoc, you can't rely on `Set wddoc = Nothing` to do it. You need to do an explicit Close, or Save and Close

So e.g.

```
        wddoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Paste
        wddoc.Close -1 ' SaveChanges:=Word.wdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges
        ' Only do this outside your "For i =" loop
        'Free alocated memory and close
        'wdapp.Quit
        Set wddoc = Nothing
        ' Only do this outside your "For i =" loop
        ' Set wdapp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have the same problem after setting  'wddoc' and 'wdapp' to 'nothing' outside of the 'For-loop'. I think i need 'wdoc.save' and 'wdoc.close' to be within the i-loop because I want to save and close the document before i open a new document. The 'wddoc' is also initialised within the for loop. I have the code to 'On Error resume next' so there may be an error causing this for the following iterations. However when I remove this error handling I get an error on line 'Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application").

Comment: Update: I have commented out Lines:  Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application").  and  'On Error resume next' as well as the rest of the error handling. I am left with the same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have done that. Revert your code back but add `On Error GoTo 0` just before `wdapp.Visible = True` That will turn error handling back to its default state.

Comment: @EmptyStack - I agree with @slightlysnarky - you need to close the document and save the changes within the loop, but quit the application outside the loop. But you should  only quit Word if `Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` fails. I would add a boolean at that point and test it later, e.g. `If quitWord then wdapp.Quit`

Comment: Incidentally there is little value to using late binding in this instance. The only advantage to late binding is version independence, i.e. you can write code in a newer version and it will theoretically work in an older one. But that advantage is lost unless you also use late binding for the host application code as Office is usually installed as a package. I find it better to use early binding when working with other Office applications and reserve late binding for other commonly used libraries, e.g. ADO, XML or Scripting.

Comment: @EmptyStack "I think i need 'wdoc.save' and 'wdoc.close' to be within the i-loop because I want to save and close the document before i open a new document" Well, that's what my post said. What happened when you did that?

Comment: @ Timothy Rylatt. Thankyou for your suggestions I will look do more research into late and early binding their differences and implementations.